# What is the second parameter passed to these functions?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {})    { }   // #1

void f(const int&, const int (&)[1])  { }   // #2
```

In those function overloads but what exactly are the second parameters.

My guess is,

#1 any empty array
#2 Returns the reference of the first index of an array

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=void+f%28int%2C+const+int+%28%26%29%5B2%5D+%29

Answer (score 2):

Both are references to arrays of the written type and size.

For example `const int (&)[2]` is a `const` lvalue reference to an array of 2 `int` (or equivalently a lvalue reference to an array of 2 `const int`).

The first one has a default argument which would create a temporary array of the given type to which the reference binds if no argument is provided in a call. That temporary array would be initialized as if by a `= {}` initializer. (In the case of type `int` this means the elements are zero-initialized.)